# How can I avoid the creation of changelogs in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to avoid the creation of changelog topics in Kafka streams using a `inMemoryWindowStore` (I am using Kafka 2.3.0 and Streams DSL), I am also calling `withLoggingDisabled()` but somehow when the application starts changelog topics are created, and also used because I can see data within them. What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid the creation of changelogs?

```
    WindowBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryWindowStore("in-mem-store-" + index,
            Duration.ofSeconds(windowRetentionPeriodInSeconds),
            Duration.ofSeconds(aggregationWindowSizeInSeconds),
            false);

    myStream.filter((key, val) -> val!=null)
            .selectKey((key, val) -> val.getId())
            .groupByKey(Grouped.as("key-grouper").with(Serdes.String(), new MyDtoSerde()))
            .aggregate(MyDto::new,
                    new MyUpdater(),
                    Materialized.as(storeSupplier)
                            .withCachingDisabled()
                            .withLoggingDisabled()
                            .with(Serdes.String(), new MyDtoSerde()))
```

Comment: I cannot spot an issue if your code. However, why do you need to create a custom `WindowBytestStoreSupplier`? You could disable logging via `Materialized.as(String).withLoggingDisabled()`, too. In any case, it sound like a bug to me. Can you create a ticket for it?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I just did https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8646 Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as explained by Bill Bejeck [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8646?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16885391#comment-16885391), the use of static methods of Materialized in 2.3.0 is a bit tricky.

I've solved the problem this way:

```
    Materialized<String, MyDto, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized;
    materialized = Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new MyDtoSerde());
    if (withLoggingDisabled) {
        materialized.withLoggingDisabled();
    }

    myStream.filter((key, val) -> val!=null)
        .selectKey((key, val) -> val.getId())
        .groupByKey(Grouped.as("key-grouper").with(Serdes.String(), new MyDtoSerde()))
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(aggregationWindowSizeInSeconds))
                   .grace(Duration.ofSeconds(windowRetentionPeriodInSeconds)))
        .aggregate(MyDto::new,
                   new MyUpdater(),
                   materialized)
```